# Why should I have a MySQL password in a separate file?

Tags: php, mysql

Perhaps naive question but I've read that I should keep my MySQL database password and db name in a separate file in a restricted folder, but why? When I inspect web pages using developer tools I can't see the PHP code, what am I missing?

Comment: to put it outside public access so that no one except your script can use it. Imagine if there is server misconfiguration. and one page leaked out.... what will happen?

Comment: probably easier than repeating login privileges and connecting over and over? put it in a file and include it when you need to connect to database, its true you cant see it from browser, but maybe another programmer/designer logs in to you server? should not it be hidden from them?

Comment: security, so password can be located outside of your www root, software design ( have config in one file)

Answer (score 4):

Well, firstly, it gives you a single place to set the password so you're not having to edit multiple files if/when the details change

Secondly, you need to consider other users on your system - is it possible that you might want to allow another developer to make changes to your site code without revealing your mysql login details? If so, you can deny them access to that folder but still allow them to edit the rest of the code base.

Comment: You're very welcome. If one of our answers helped, please consider marking it as accepted using the tick on the left - This saves other devs from attempting to solve a problem that's already been resolved. Of course, if you need more information / details, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2):

1. There have been cases where server errors/misconfigurations have led to PHP code being displayed in the user's browser (see: Facebook a few years ago). Because of this, a lot of developers place their MySQL connection details in a file that is kept outside of the web root.
2. [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle: Don't repeat yourself. i.e. Don't have repeating code. This makes code far more manageable. Imagine the hardship of having to edit 500 PHP files just because your MySQL password changed? What if you have to connect to a different MySQL server?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, we suggest to put every credentials in separate file not just mysql username and password .

1. It is because your production server may have different password and username . So to reflect change everywhere it is good to use single file and `require` it in your file .
2. with source control , we can easily ignore it so that password is non-shared between team members .
3. we need to give special permisson mostly `700` to that file .
4. It is good pratice to follow DRY (dont repeat yourself principle )